how can I make a character move in my game using c without the use of any game engine?
Im not sure how to do this because all the tutorials I have searched for implement game engines which I can not. its a 2d game and the character will be moving up down left and right.
none of the  tutorials out there are applicable so if any one could point me in the right direction that woul

What are you using for graphics?

The answer is: you write your own “game engine”.
By that I mean that you must have, at minimum:

a way to put graphics to the display / terminal
a way to obtain non-buffered key input
a proper timing loop (for event processing)

The easiest way to get all these is using a known game engine, but you can do it yourself fairly easily (if you really want to reinvent the wheel).
You said:

none of the tutorials out there are applicable

Nonsense. There are literally thousands of tutorials out there for every imaginable system. Your question did not indicate what system(s) you are targeting, so we cannot even guess.
I recommend you avoid doing console text graphics for the game. There is a whole lot of magic to doing that correctly that will make your learning much more difficult than it need be.
Instead, pick a known graphics package and use it. I can personally recommend PyGame, Godot, and SFML as good places to get started. PyGame uses Python, but it is really, really easy and friendly and it has many example games for you to play with as well as excellent tutorials. Godot uses a python derivative naturally, but you can also use C (or C++) with it, and is significantly more powerful than either of the other two. SFML is a pure C (with C++ bindings) system that is easy to set up. SO discourages recommendations, so you are getting a weird freebee from me here.
